# Flutter Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max and pod install

Tags: ios, flutter

After updating xcode to 12.1 my flutter app was not able to install pods and launch on iPhone 12 pro max or earlier:
I tried to change the IOS Deployment Target to higher than 8.0 but same error!

I tried these steps to reproduce it but was not successful:

```
rm ios/Podfile
flutter clean
flutter run
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by running:

```
flutter clean
pod cache clean  --all
rm -rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework

flutter pub get
pod install
flutter run
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on my MacBook M1 chip.

I solved this by quitting Android Studio and virtual devices and by running:

on terminal:

```
flutter upgrade --force
```

and in Android Studio project terminal:

```
arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi
rm ios/Podfile
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

write these command on project root terminal

```
flutter clean
pod cache clean  --all
rm -rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework

flutter pub get
flutter upgrade --force
```

if necessary use

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved the issue on my side regarding this it was an issue with the FVM version on Dart and the FVM version of Dart and I just delete it with

```
brew remove dart
```

and run the app normally
There was an issue with linker on my side!