# Error launching application on iPhone Flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm unable to test my flutter application on VSCode which is running on catalina on vitual box.

After launching application from VSCode, I am just getting single line error `Error launching application on Najam’s iPhone.` and then application is opening in the device but it is then disconnected with VSCode

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Najam’s iPhone in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: H5PHS46J86
Running pod install...                 277.5s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...   114.5s
Xcode build done.                      346.8s
Installing and launching...            59.8s
Error launching application on Najam’s iPhone.
```

**What I've tried**

As suggested here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/69632#issuecomment-803646337, I tried below solution but it didn't work for me

> - Setting `platform to 10.0` inside the Podfile (platform :ios, '10.0' )
> - Doing a combination of `flutter clean`, `pod cache clean --all` and `pod install`

I also tried this solution too https://stackoverflow.com/a/64661277/7290043. But it didn't work either.

> - flutter clean  pod cache clean  --all
> - rm -rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
> - flutter pub get
> - pod install
> - flutter run

What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The time to launch is very long. What type of machine are you building on? VSCode debugging might just be timing out. Try running directly from xcode and a) see if it remains connected, and b) see if any further errors are reported

Comment: Thanks for responce. Yes it works fine with xcode. But problem is that I can't debug my app properly with xcode. On VScode I use debug console and use `print` statment to get to the bottom of the problem. But unfortunately I'm getting the above error in VSCode. Is there any way to run application in VScode? @agreensh

Answer (score -1):

Same issue, I fixed it:

1. flutter/bin/cache,delete flutter_tools.snapshot and flutter_tools.stamp;
2. flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/ios/devices.dart, find 'await observatoryDiscovery.uri.timeout(const Duration(seconds: 60))'
3. Then change 60 to 240
4. flutter run
5. wow, success